# Can an invisible neutron star exist?

Tags: visible-light, black-holes, neutron-stars

Basically a neutron/quark star that approaches it's Schwarzschild radius but doesn't surpass it. Its gravitational force is great enough to not let light escape from it, but not great enough to become a black hole.

Comment: If light _can't_ escape, then it _is_ a black hole, but the deeper a light source falls into a gravity well, the more the photons that escape will be red-shifted when they climb out.  For any given light source, there will be some amount of red shift that makes the photons _effectively_ undetectable even though, technically speaking, they do "escape."

Comment: Maybe you can look this, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetospheric_eternally_collapsing_object

Answer (score 1):

If it is not a black hole, then light can escape from it. Why? Because a black hole is defined as something light cannot escape from.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "no" because only for a black hole can light never escape.
However, this question deserves a fuller answer because of a thing called the "photon sphere".

At the Schwartzchild radius of a compact body - whose mass is all inside the radius - light can no longer escape.  However, at a distance which is 1.5 times the Schwartzchild radius there is a thing called the photon sphere.  Any light incident on a massive body that comes from the outside of the photon sphere and enters it will invariably be "sucked into" the body.  Light that originates within the photon sphere, but outside the Schwartzchild radius, and is directed outwards, may still escape however.  This opens up the possibility that there exist objects so massive that their mass is within a photon sphere but not within the Schwartzchild radius.  Such objects would likely be neutron stars.

Now the fun part - what do we mean by "invisible"?  If by "invisible" we mean "I shine light on it and zero of it is ever reflected" then the answer to your question is "yes"!